# How to Solve the "304 Not Modified" Warning? (jQuery UI, Ruby on Rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.2

*Notice: The question has been edited.*

## The Problem:

The adding of `jQuery UI 1.9` to `Ruby on Rails 3.2` has caused a ***slow loading time*** of the web page.

## The Warning Message:

```
Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/development-bundle/ui/minified/i18n/
jquery.ui.datepicker-tj.min.js?body=1" for *[localhost]*
Served asset /jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/development-bundle/ui/minified/i18n/jquery.
ui.datepicker-tj.min.js - 304 Not Modified (15ms)
```

This protocol message does re-occur repeatedly. How can this `304 Not Modified` warning be solved?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with Webrick.  If you use `thin` instead, the problem will cease (also, `thin` is usually faster)

https://rubygems.org/gems/thin

If you're totally set on using Webrick, you can try using [this patch](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/attachments/2300/204_304_keep_alive.patch)

In the future, please ask only one question when posting.  If another error comes out of it, append it to the current problem if it's relevant (generally this is stuff like debugging information).  Otherwise, open a new question for it.

In the case of the 304, it's not really a warning as much as just information.  It can be a warning if things aren't behaving properly, but normally it's fine.  In this case, what the 304 is telling you is that the contents are cached and have not been modified by the request to the server.  This is done for performance reasons.  If you want to make the 304 go away, you could try turning off caching in rails.  However, generally, rails is smart enough to bust the cache and send you the new asset if you modify it.

Here's a [reference for status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

For a reference on caching, you might want to start with the [Rails Guide on Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)

Comment: Thanks, the `line 205` of the patch has caused `one` warning to be solved. I have edited the question.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. It does work in Internet Explorer without a call for the repeated request, yet on the contrary Firefox does do the call for the repeated request, (even after having the cache and cookies cleared). The question is by which factor Firefox is causing the call for the repeated request.

Comment: I'm not sure what the root of this problem is, but I think you're confusing the local cache with the server cache.  `304 Not Modified` means that rails cached the file and told your client to use the most recent version.  If you clear your local cache, the server still has cached, previously rendered HTML.  This is what the 304 is talking about.  Please note that this is **not** an error.  It's just informative